# Simple internet traffic whitelist

Tags: internet, proxy, opendns

I've been searching like crazy trying to find a solution to a problem that seems like it ought to be very simple.

All I want to do is block all internet access at the system level, except for a handful of hostnames.

OpenDNS cannot do this, Dan's Guardian is ridiculously complicated, and I can't find a way to set up a proxy server at system level, only at browser level.

Can you, for example, block all traffic in the `hosts.deny` file and then add the needed sites to `hosts.allow`?  Or can it be done through `ufw`?